# Porque no me aparece el botón de la clase JButton en el Frame?

Tags: java

```
package bienvenidos;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CapturaDatos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PantallaCaptura pantalla1=new PantallaCaptura();
        pantalla1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class PantallaCaptura extends JFrame{

        public PantallaCaptura() {
            setTitle("Pantalla de Captura");
            setBounds(400,200,400,400);
            setVisible(true);
            add(new LaminaCaptura());
        }   
}

 class LaminaCaptura extends JPanel{

    public LaminaCaptura(){
     boton1=new JButton("CapturarDato");
     }

     JButton boton1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas añadir el botón al panel

```
class LaminaCaptura extends JPanel{

    public LaminaCaptura(){
       this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       boton1=new JButton("CapturarDato");
       add(boton1);
    }

     JButton boton1;
 }
```

Si lo quieres de forma específica tendrás que añadir layouts.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html

Comment: Ya lo había hecho pero tampoco funciona. Ya se lo agregue y sigue sin funcionar, no sé si tenga que ver porque estoy utilizando la versión JEE

Comment: Intenta poniéndole un flow, he editado el código para que lo cheques

Answer (score 0):

```
package bienvenidos;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

    public class CapturaDatos {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PantallaCaptura pantalla1=new PantallaCaptura();
            pantalla1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }

    class PantallaCaptura extends JFrame{
            public PantallaCaptura() {
            setTitle("Pantalla de Captura");
                setBounds(400,200,400,400);
                setVisible(true);
                add(new LaminaCaptura());
            }   
    }

     class LaminaCaptura extends JPanel{

        public LaminaCaptura(){
         boton1=new JButton("CapturarDato");
         add(boton1);
         }

         JButton boton1;
     }
```